# Removing Desktop Environment

Tags: desktop-environment

How can I remove a desktop environment? If I use KDE in CentOS, how can I remove the default GNOME environment to avoid file conflict?

Comment: This doesn’t answer your question, but you can install KDE and GNOME in parallel without file conflicts, and Fedora and CentOS aren’t derivatives of each other.

Comment: Does that include KDE Plasma or is KDE Plasma referred to as KDE?

Comment: KDE Plasma is referred to as KDE, but you can install multiple desktops in Linux without any problem, no matter the desktop.

Answer (score 1):

There will be no file conflicts with installing `KDE Plasma` and `GNOME`; however if you wish to save space:

Use this command to remove Gnome Desktop:

```
yum remove @gnome-desktop
```

Comment: what is the command used to remove desktop environments in debian-based distros

Comment: It would be `sudo apt-get remove gnome-desktop` (I though CentOS used Yum?)

Comment: Yes centOS does use yum i was just using CentOS as an example

Comment: Then please specify your distro in the question. Please, if this works, mark this question as the answer with the tick underneath the down arrow.